# Store pointer to object in SQLite in Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, pointers

I've a tree of objC/Swift objects. They represent graphical objects, which I want to query based on location and other properties.

Since SQLite supports an RTree table, I store the boundary boxes and relevant properties in tables along side a pointer to the original object. When I retrieve a result I can easily get the original object. This works fine in objC with the following conversions:

pointer to int: `(intptr_t)self`

int to pointer: `(__bridge SomeObject *)(void *)(intptr_t)pointerValue`

I'm updating the code and also converting to Swift. Unfortunately I can't find a way to do something equivalent in Swift. I've found `withUnsafePointer()`, but it states that the pointer is only valid inside the closure. It also doesn't seem to be possible to get the actual pointer value as an `Int` from `UnsafePointer`. It only has a `hashValue` property.

How can I get a pointer in Swift which I can store in SQLite?

Note: The SQLite database is in memory and I can guarantee that the objects will stay around as long as they are 'referenced' from the database. There is no need for any kind of long lived persistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Unmanaged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged). For example (Swift 3):

```
class MyClass {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

func makeInt(from obj: MyClass) -> Int {
    let unmanaged = Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj)
    return Int(bitPattern: unmanaged.toOpaque())
}

func makeObj(from int: Int) -> MyClass? {
    guard let pointer = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: int) else {
        return nil
    }
    let unmanaged = Unmanaged<MyClass>.fromOpaque(pointer)
    return unmanaged.takeUnretainedValue()
}

let obj = MyClass(name: "foo")
let int = makeInt(from: obj)

if let obj2 = makeObj(from: int) {
    print(obj2.name) // "foo"
}
```

The use of "unretained" values means that no memory management happens: it's your responsibility to keep objects alive.